# Referencing a range that is input into the function is causing the code to stop

Tags: excel, vba, input, range, cell

this is both my first post on stack overflow and my first vba project so please forgive and correct any mistakes.

I am trying to create a function that looks at two ranges and pastes only non-null duplicate values into a third range.

My function takes in the two ranges that are to be compared as input (`rangeOne` and `rangeTwo`). It also takes in a third range, which is the first cell in the paste range (`strtCell`). I am trying to make it so that the duplicate values are pasted along a column for now, but so that they start at the cell that the user inputs.

The problem is that whenever I reference `strtCell`, the code just stops running. I have tested various breakpoints and using strtCell in many different contexts. However, whenever it is used at all in the code, the code stops executing at that line without any error message. If I comment out or delete the lines referencing it, the cell I enter the function in is set to "Success" as expected.

Also as an aside, whenever I type Option Explicit on the top line, it disappears from the workspace but still seems to be in effect. I am confused as to why it is disappearing.

Here is the relevant code [I put the bracketed text for comments I added in the post]:

```
(Option Explicit)    
Public Function CopyDuplicates(rangeOne As Range, strtCell As Range, rangeTwo As Range)
    
    'Declare necessary things
    Dim arrayOne(), arrayTwo(), element, element2, element3, element4
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim pairs As New Collection
    pairs.Add ""
    
    Dim flag As Boolean
    
    Dim numberOfDuplicateValues As Integer, i As Integer
    numberOfDuplicateValues = 0
    i = 0
    
    
    'Import the Ranges
        
        'Set array lengths to sizes of ranges
        ReDim arrayOne(rangeOne.Count - 1)
        ReDim arrayTwo(rangeTwo.Count - 1)
        
        'Set array values to values of ranges
            
            'Range 1
            For Each cell In rangeOne
                arrayOne(i) = cell.Value
                i = i + 1
            Next cell
        
            'Range 2
            [Exact same process as Range 1]
    
    'Check for Duplicates
    [This is just some code that adds all the duplicate values into pairs. 
    I have used a breakpoint to verify that pairs is being updated as intended.]
    
    'Print duplicates
    For Each element4 In pairs
        strtCell.Value = CStr(element4)
        strtCell = strtCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next element4
    
    CopyDuplicates = "Success"
End Function
```

I'll also just add that strtCell is meant to be a single-cell range, but I have tested it as both a single and multi cell range, with the same weird stopping result in both cases.

Thanks for any help, this problem has had me stumped for hours!

Comment: If you call a User-defined Function (UDF) from the spreadsheet, any runtime error will cause the function to terminate without error messages. To debug, it is usually helpful to write a test Sub macro in VBA that calls the function to test it (using hard-coded ranges for example). Any errors will then be reported. Without trying your code, my guess is that it should be `Set strtCell = strtCell.Offset(1, 0)`.

Comment: A function called as  UDF can only return a value (or values if returning an array) to the calling cell(s) - it can't update other cells on a worksheet.  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, that’s a much more fundamental reason! The OP should instead have the list of non-dupes as the return value of their function, and put the formula in the cell where the output is wanted.

Comment: I don't see enough code to be able to trace exactly what you are trying to do.  For example, what is supposed to be in `pairs` collection?  I see an empty string added at the top only.  What happens if `rangeOne` and `rangeTwo` are different sizes?  Can you show a screenshot of a spreadsheet that shows before and after what is supposed to happen?  I don't see enough for a minimally reproducible example to provide you the help you need: [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your very helpful response! For this project, I can implement a button to call a sub that calls the function for the relevant ranges.

Comment: @DS_London Thanks for explaining why I am not getting any errors, that part was bothering me a bunch!

Comment: In terms of suitability and maintainability, i find it better to first try and achieve the task through existing, in-built spreadsheet functions: which you can do for this particular task. People reach for VBA too soon IMHO, without exploring the alternatives. One major advantage is that the workbook can be saved as .xlsx, not .xlsm, which will avoid security warnings and trust issues.